# When creating a UI scene in Unity, should I render the canvas in camera space?

Tags: unity, camera

I'm working on a scene that is strictly going to be used for character creation.  Can anyone explain what the best practice is for a scene like this?  Should I render the canvas to the camera, or should I render it in world space, or as an overlay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing for your purposes, you're going to want to use screen space overlay.

Take a look at the Unity Manual: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UICanvas.html

You probably don't want your UI to be affected by perspective, and you don't have any reason for the camera to move and have your UI not move with it, which is what you would use world space for.